# jquery form .submit() only works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, forms, google-chrome, submit

I'm trying to post a form that created dynamically, and see the result in a new window,
and it only works in Chrome.
Both FF and IE just do nothing when hitting that code.

```
$('<form>').attr({ method: 'POST', action: data.Url, target: '_blank' })
    .append($('<input>').attr({ type: 'hidden', name: 'Field1', value: data.field1Data }))
    .append($('<input>').attr({ type: 'hidden', name: 'Field2', value: data.field2Data }))
    .submit();
```

What can cause that?

Comment: could you provide a live example of your code?

Comment: I expect IE to not work because in IE you can't set/change the type attribute of an input after it is created. I would have expected it to work in FF though, I suspect it's failing for a similar reason.

Comment: @KevinB you can set type initially in IE, you can't change the type of an established input. There is a difference. I know jQuery *docs* ([the source code only checks established inputs](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L378)) say otherwise, but I have tested it in IE6-9. I will probably make the bug report some day..

Answer (score 5):

The form needs to be in the document at least in IE, probably in firefox too it seems:

```
$('<form>').attr({ method: 'POST', action: data.Url, target: '_blank' })
    .append($('<input>').attr({ type: 'hidden', name: 'Field1', value: data.field1Data }))
    .append($('<input>').attr({ type: 'hidden', name: 'Field2', value: data.field2Data }))
    .appendTo("body")
    .submit()
    .remove();
```

Comment: You might also want to hide the form before you append it, in this case.

Comment: Thanks! Appending it to body does the job.

Answer (score 0):

try appending the form inside your html first, add at the end before calling submit() eg:

```
.appendTo('body').submit();
```